# SQL performances of selecting recently modified records Solr

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, solr

I have a SQL Server 2916 database, and Solr.
The Solr indexer runs often such queries:

```
select book_collection from books group by book_collection having max(updated_on) > '2017-04-04 09:50:05'
```

The column updated_on is updated by a trigger on insert/update; at every run of the Solr incremental indexer (every 10 minutes), many queries like the above get the latest modified records and reindexes them.
This table, for instance, has about one million rows and at every time the query would return 10-20 rows maximum.
These queries end up in the list of the most expensive queries run on the database, so I would like to optimize them.
My questions:

1) Would a timestamp column perform better than a datetime column?

2) If I changed the query like this, would it be more efficient?

```
select distinct book_collection from books where updated_on > '2017-04-04 09:50:05'
```

The first query plan is the original one, the second is modified by me. The fact that the second plan asks for an index, and the first one doesn't, really suggests that the modified query can use an index, if present, and is therefore better.

[image: Original]

[image: Modified by me]

Comment: Is there an index on the updated on column? Can you also provide the query plan?

Comment: Not yet, but I plan to add it.

Comment: Can you add the query plan? Then I can see what your query actually does.

Comment: The first query might benefit from an index on `(book_collection, updated_on)`. The 2nd from an index on `(updated_on) INCLUDE (book_collection)`

Comment: Change the `HAVING` to a `WHERE` and you get the same effect without having to use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: 1) No, changing the datatype is unlikely to have a significant performance impact.  (never mind the other problems with it).  2) The `DISTINCT` isn't better, you've just changed the logic of the query.  You could achieve the same thing by moving the conditional test from the HAVING clause to a WHERE clause.  What you need is an appropriate index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a `timestamp` is a 8 bytes and a `datetime` is 8 bytes, there will be no appreciable difference between the two in terms of performance.

Adding an appropriate index will make a much larger difference in the work required for SQL Server to fulfill the SOLR query.

To test this, I've created the following minimally complete verifiable example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Books', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Books;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Books
(
    BookID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Books
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , Book_Collection varchar(30) NOT NULL
    , updated_on datetime NOT NULL
    , Pad varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

;WITH Nums AS (
    SELECT v.Num
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))v(Num)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Books (Book_Collection, updated_on, Pad)
SELECT v1.Num + v2.num * 10 + v2.num * 100
    , DATEADD(MINUTE, 0 - (v2.Num * 10 + v3.Num * 100), GETDATE())
    , CONVERT(varchar(100), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(100))
FROM Nums v1
    CROSS JOIN Nums v2
    CROSS JOIN Nums v3
    CROSS JOIN Nums v4;
GO
```

The above inserts 10,000 rows across 1,000 `book_collection` values, with varying `updated_on` values.

My example SOLR query:

```
SELECT b.Book_Collection
FROM dbo.Books b
GROUP BY b.Book_Collection
HAVING MAX(b.updated_on) > DATEADD(MINUTE, 0 - 3, GETDATE())
```

The plan for this query:

[image]

Stats for this query:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:
>     CPU time = 16 ms, elapsed time = 26 ms.
>
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0,   >read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Books'. Scan count 1, logical reads 164, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>     CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 57 ms.

If we add this index, and re-run the same query:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Books_Collection
ON dbo.Books (Book_Collection, updated_on);
```

We see the following plan and statistics:

[image]

> SQL Server parse and compile time:
>     CPU time = 8 ms, elapsed time = 8 ms.
>
> Table 'Books'. Scan count 1, logical reads 33, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>     CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 6 ms.

I/O is substantially reduced, as is CPU time and elapsed time.  Clearly, adding a helpful index will make the query more efficient.

If we re-create the experiment using a `timestamp` column in place of the `datetime` column, we see very similar results:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Books', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Books;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Books
(
    BookID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Books
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , Book_Collection varchar(30) NOT NULL
    , updated_on timestamp NOT NULL
    , Pad varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

;WITH Nums AS (
    SELECT v.Num
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))v(Num)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Books (Book_Collection, Pad)
SELECT v1.Num + v2.num * 10 + v2.num * 100, CONVERT(varchar(100), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(100))
FROM Nums v1
    CROSS JOIN Nums v2
    CROSS JOIN Nums v3
    CROSS JOIN Nums v4;
GO
```

Stats for the query without the index in place:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:
>     CPU time = 15 ms, elapsed time = 19 ms.
>
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Books'. Scan count 1, logical reads 164, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>     CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 3 ms.

And with the index in place:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:
>     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
>
> Table 'Books'. Scan count 1, logical reads 33, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>     CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 5 ms.

Answer (score 3):

1. In SQL Server, TIMESTAMP does not represent a time, it's just a number representing the rowversion. So it's unlikely you can just change the datatype of that column for performance reasons.
2. Yes, that will probably perform better, because it can use the index over `updated_on`, something the MAX()-function prohibits in the original query. As far as I can see, the result should be identical.

Comment: I know what is a timestamp. I can confirm that the column updated_on is only used for the purpose of fetching the records modified since last run, the date is not used for other reasons. So in my opinion it should be possible to replace it. Am I missing something?

Comment: *"the date is only used for the purpose of fetching the records modified since last run"*. Which means that Solr is updating and retrieving values from that column expecting that it is a datetime column. If you modify its type, Solr will probably complain. carlo, , that's what *"unlikely you can just change the datatype"* means.

Comment: Yes, of course the Solr configuration should be changed too. Thanks for the clarification.